# Why does my int output something different than what it's supposed to?

Tags: c++, integer

My `bin` in my second-to-last line displays something like `3282692812` when it's meant to be different. Everything else is fine, I have tried searching online but I can't find anything about it.

```
string a;
int amount;
cout << "1-10k 2-2k 3-1k: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "\n";
cout << "How many numbers do you want to be generated?: ";
cin >> amount;
cout << "\n";
long bin = 0;



if (int(a) = 1)
{
    bin = 60457811425;
}
else if (a == 2)
{
    bin = 60457811474;
}
else if (a == 3)
{
    bin = 6045781165;
}

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    cout << bin << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << rand() % 10 << "|" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << rand() % (13 - 1) + 1 << "|" << rand() % (2031 - 2022) + 2022 << "|" << setw(3) << setfill('0') << rand() % 999 << "\n";
}

system("pause");
```

Comment: If the `bin` value that's being displayed isn't correct, you can remove all of those calls to `rand()`, because they're just distraction. Also, displaying it more than once isn't needed.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "when it's meant to be different". What output are you expecting from the program?

Comment: I'm surprised `60457811425` doesn't warn about overflowing.

Answer (score 5):

You only converted to `a` to an `int` once, you didn't do it with a legal converter ("constructing" an `int` from a `std::string` doesn't work like that, and I'd be surprised if your compiler didn't warn you), and you *assigned* to the result (`=`) rather than *comparing* (`==`) (also something I'd expect a compiler to warn you about).

**Later checked about those warnings**: As it happens, it looks like `gcc` accepts both constructs in tandem as a completely different construct (it interprets `if (int(a) = 1)` as *declaring* a shadowing `int` variable named `a`, initialized to `1`, that expires after the `if`/`else if` chain; that's fun). It only warns at all if you compile with `-Wall`, and even then, it only complains because it thinks it should be `if (int a = 1)` to make the name shadowing variable without extraneous parentheses, ugh. Bright side is that fixing the assignment to a comparison would then reveal the other problem. That's a good reason to always compile with warnings turned up (`-Wextra` is sometimes overly chatty, but `-Wall` is almost always pointing out real problems), sadly it's a rather indirect warning in this case.

Convert it once up front [with a valid `string` to `int` converter like `std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and then test the converted `int` value against other `int`s, not `std::string` against `int`, e.g.:

```
const int aint = std::stoi(a);
if (aint == 1)  // Using ==, not =
{
    bin = 60457811425;
}
else if (aint == 2)  // Testing int == int, not string == int
{
    bin = 60457811474;
}
else if (aint == 3)  // Testing int == int, not string == int
{
    bin = 6045781165;
}
```

Or for slightly more succinct code (and no extra named variables):

```
switch(std::stoi(a)) {
    case 1: bin = 60457811425; break;
    case 2: bin = 60457811474; break;
    case 3: bin = 6045781165; break;
    /* Maybe put a default case here to handle invalid input? */
}
```

Comment: Surprised at the compiler warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/7aEs7P39Y GCC complained about the brackets and sort-of leaked the fact that it declared a new variable rather than converting the value. Clang said nothing. Visual Studio was most clear, warning about the shadowing. In all cases I had to crank up the warning level to get a diagnostic.

Comment: Nobody caught the assignment, but if you replace it with a comparison, all three compilers quite rightly flip smurf: https://godbolt.org/z/WWj4P9478

Comment: _it interprets if (int(a) = 1) as declaring a shadowing int variable named a initialized to 1 that expires after the if; that's fun_ Wow, sure is.  Pointless source code contructs R us.

Comment: @user4581301: Yep, I edited to comment on that in the second paragraph. With `-Wall`, GCC complained "warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of ‘a’ [-Wparentheses]", implicating the open paren after `int` in `if (int(a) = 1)`, but having no issues with the declaration itself (using `if (int a = 1)` gets no warnings at all). I guess it's standards-legal to make the name-shadowing declaration, so it's just a warning about the chosen syntax. Such fun. Every time I think "No sane compiler would let that pass without a warning", I'm regularly disappointed.

Comment: Suspicion: Asker exchanged the compare for an assignment to eliminate the compiler errors and accidentally dug a deeper hole. Careful when making a change solely to eliminate compiler errors unless you know why it eliminates the error.

Comment: @user4581301: Yeah, on seeing how the incremental fixes actually make the compiler angrier (changing mild warnings to pages of angry errors), I can absolutely see that. "Oh, it doesn't like `if (a == 1)`, gotta cast it, make it `if (int(a) == 1)`. Oh, still doesn't like that, let's try dropping an `=`. Hey that works, and it even fixes the errors with `a == 2` and `a == 3`, great! Hmm... why isn't it working?"

Comment: @user4581301 It's actually quite useful if you think about RAII: `if (auto guard = mymutex.try_lock()) { ... }`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I'm sure there are the occasional use cases, but that's not one of them as written; `try_lock` returns a `bool`, with no RAII features (you'd be responsible for unlocking manually). You'd want something like: `if (auto guard = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex, std::try_to_lock)) { ... }` to get the RAII features (conveniently, `std::unique_lock` does implement `operator bool` to return `true` only when the lock is held). That's... fairly dense. I'd probably just introduce an extra scope with braces and multiline that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger MyMutex is a bit different in my kernel because I always want RAII.